# Count how many time each Char is in a txt file in C#

Tags: c#, list, sorting, dictionary

I have a school homework, where I need to count how many times each letter is in a txt file, I can't use a dictionary and can't use LinQ, I then need to put it in order alphabetically, and in order of iterations.

```
string = "hello world"
```

```
output = 

D=1
E=1
H=1
L=3
O=2
R=1
W=1

L=3
O=2
D=1
E=1
H=1
R=1
W=1
```

What I have so far works just for the order alphabetically , not for the itterations.

```
public void testChar() {

  string text = File.ReadAllText(@ "C:\Ecole\Session 2\Prog\Bloc 4\test.txt")?.ToUpper();

  text = Regex.Replace(text, @ "[^a-zA-Z]", "");

  List < char > listChar = new List < char > ();

  foreach(char lettre in text) {
    listChar.Add(lettre);
  }

  int countPosition = 0;

  List < int > position = new List < int > ();

  listOfChar.Add(listChar[0]);

  listOfRepetitions.Add(1);

  position.Add(countPosition);

  int jumpFirstItteration = 0;

  foreach(var item in listChar) {
    if (jumpFirstItteration == 0) {
      jumpFirstItteration++;

    }

    if (listOfChar.Contains(item)) {
      int pos = listOfChar.IndexOf(item);
      listOfRepetitions[pos] += 1;

    } else if (!listOfChar.Contains(item)) {

      listOfChar.Add(item);
      listOfRepetitions.Add(1);

      countPosition++;
      position.Add(countPosition);

    }

  }

}
```

Please help :D

Comment: They likely want you to use an `int` array where index 0 = a, 1 = b and so on and just increment the the indexes of the array as you see the characters.  Like `var count = new int[26];  foreach(var c in text) count[c - 'a']++;` assuming all the characters are a to b lower case.

Comment: @juharr it can become tricky to sort this kind of array alphabetically and retain the frequency

Comment: @Sébastien it's already in alphabetical order.  It just requires a bit of work to sort on the frequencies while keeping track of the original indexes to get the second ordering.

Comment: @juharr, right, I meant "tricky to sort in frequency order", not "alphabetical".

Answer (score 1):

The canonical way of computing a concordance is to use an array of integers for counting the letters, the same size as the number of different letters in the text - in this case, just the normal uppercase alphabetic characters A-Z.

Then you iterate through the uppercased letters and if they are in range, increment the count corresponding to that letter.

To simplify this you can make two observations:

- To convert a letter to an index, just subtract 'A' from the character code.
- To convert an index to a letter, just add 'A' to the index and cast the result back to a char. (The cast is necessary because the result of adding an int to a char is an int, not a char.)

Once you've done that, you'll have all the counts for the characters in alphabetical order. However, you also need the  letters in order of frequency of occurrence. To compute that, you can use [an overload of Array.Sort() that takes two arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.sort?view=net-5.0#System_Array_Sort_System_Array_System_Array_): The first parameter is an array to sort, and the second parameter is an array to sort in the same way as the first array.

If you pass the array of counts as the first array, and an array of all the letters being counted in alphabetical order as the second array (i.e. the letters A..Z) then after sorting the second array will give you the letters in the correct order to display with the first array.

Putting all that together:

```
public void testChar()
{
    string filename    = @"C:\Ecole\Session 2\Prog\Bloc 4\test.txt";
    string text        = File.ReadAllText(filename).ToUpper();
    int[]  concordance = new int[26]; // 26 different letters of the alphabet to count.

    foreach (char c in text)
    {
        int index = c - 'A';  // A..Z will convert to 0..25; other chars will be outside that range.

        if (index >= 0 && index < 26)
            ++concordance[index];
    }

    // Display frequency in alphabetic order, omitting chars with 0 occurances.
    for (int i = 0; i < concordance.Length; ++i)
    {
        if (concordance[i] > 0)
            Console.WriteLine($"{(char)('A'+i)} = {concordance[i]}");
    }

    Console.WriteLine();

    // For sorting by frequency we need another array of chars A..Z in alphabetical order.
    char[] aToZ = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToCharArray();
    Array.Sort(concordance, aToZ);

    // Display frequency in occurance order, omitting chars with 0 occurances.
    for (int i = 0; i < concordance.Length; ++i)
    {
        if (concordance[i] > 0)
            Console.WriteLine($"{aToZ[i]} = {concordance[i]}");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe add something like a sort function?

```
    position.sort((a,b)=> if a < b return 1; if a > b return -1; return 0;)
```

This would be a normal sorting function based on their integer value, but since you are dealing with a list, it becomes a little more tedious.

```
    position.sort((a,b)=> if a[i] < b[i] return 1; if a[i] > b[i] return -1; return 0;)
```

where i the index of integers to be compared

Forgive me, I come from java

Comment: This is very unlikely to be accepted as a homework solution :)

Comment: In C# `List<T>.Sort(Comparison<T>)` accepts a sorting delegate that does just the same.

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions that may come in handy.
You could build a container (the `CharInfo` class object here), to store the information you collect about each char found, it's position and how many times it's found in your text file.
This class *container* implements [IComparable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable-1) (the comparer just tests the char value, as an integer, against the char value of another object).
This makes it simple to sort a `List<CharInfo>`, just calling its [Sort()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort) method:

```
public class CharInfo : IComparable<CharInfo>
{
    public CharInfo(char letter, int position) {
        Character = letter;
        Positions.Add(position);
    }

    public char Character { get; }
    public int Occurrences { get; set; } = 1;
    public List<int> Positions { get; } = new List<int>();
    public static List<string> CharsFound { get; } = new List<string>();

    public int CompareTo(CharInfo other) => this.Character - other.Character;
}
```

Since you can use the Regex class, you can then use [Regex.Matches()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches) to return all characters in the `[a-zA-Z]` range. Each [Match](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.match) object also stores the position where the character was found.

(As a note, you could just use the Matches collection and `GroupBy()` the results, but you cannot use LINQ and the other *suggestions* would just be mute :)

Looping the `Matches` collection, you test whether a char is already present in the list; if it is, add `1` to the `Occurrences` Property and add its position to the `Positions` Property.
If it's not already there, add a new `CharInfo` object to the collection. The constructor of the class takes a char and a position. The `Occurrences` Property defaults to `1` (you create a new `CharInfo` because you have found a new char, which is occurrence n° 1).

In the end, just `Sort()` the collection using its custom comparer. `Sort()` will call the [IComparable.CompareTo()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable-1.compareto) method of the class.

```
string text = File.ReadAllText([File Path]);
var matches = Regex.Matches(text, @"[a-zA-Z]", RegexOptions.Multiline);
var charsInfo = new List<CharInfo>();
        
foreach (Match m in matches) {
    int pos = CharInfo.CharsFound.IndexOf(m.Value);
    if (pos >= 0) {
        charsInfo[pos].Occurrences += 1;
        charsInfo[pos].Positions.Add(m.Index);
    }
    else {
        CharInfo.CharsFound.Add(m.Value);
        charsInfo.Add(new CharInfo(m.Value[0], m.Index));
    }
}

// Sort the List<CharInfo> using the provided comparer
charsInfo.Sort();
```

- Call `CharInfo.CharsFound.Clear()` before you search another text file.

You can then print the results as:

```
foreach (var chInfo in charsInfo) {
    Console.WriteLine(
        $"Char: {chInfo.Character} " +
        $"Occurrences: {chInfo.Occurrences} " +
        $"Positions: {string.Join(",", chInfo.Positions)}");
}
```

Note that upper and lower case chars are treated as distinct elements.
Modify as required.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarilly the most efficient, but works.

First, a simple letter class thant can compare its properies.

```cs
 public class Letter
    {
        public char Symbole { get; set; }
        public int Frequency { get; set; }
   

        public int CompareLetter(object obj)
        {
            Letter other = obj as Letter;
            
            if (other == null) return 1;
            
            return this.Symbole.CompareTo(other.Symbole);
        }
        public int CompareFrequency(object obj)
        {
            Letter other = obj as Letter;

            if (other == null) return 1;

            return this.Frequency.CompareTo(other.Frequency);
        }
    }
```

Then a method to populate a List of Letter

```cs
 public static List<Letter> ReturnLettersCount(string fileName)
        {
            string text;
            List<Letter> letters = new List<Letter>();

            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName))
            {
                text = sr.ReadToEnd().ToLower();
            }

            foreach (char c in text)
            {
                if (char.IsLetter(c))
                {
                    Letter letter = letters.Find((letter) => letter.Symbole == c);
                    if (letter == null)
                    {
                        letters.Add(new Letter() { Symbole = c, Frequency = 1 });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        letter.Frequency++;
                    }
                }
            }

            return letters;
        }
```

And a user code

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string fileName = @"path\to\your\textFile.txt";

            List<Letter> letters = ReturnLettersCount(fileName);

            letters.Sort( (a, b) => a.CompareLetter(b) );
            foreach(Letter letter in letters)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{letter.Symbole}: {letter.Frequency}");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("--------------------------");
            
            letters.Sort((b, a) => a.CompareFrequency(b));
            foreach (Letter letter in letters)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{letter.Symbole}: {letter.Frequency}");
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Without Linq and Dictionary it's like walking by foot to the grocery 20 miles away. ;)

```
//C# vs >= 8.0
using System;
using Entry = System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<char, int>;    

   // class header ...
    public static void Sort() {

        var text    = "hello world";
        var contest = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Entry>(text.Length);

        foreach (var c in text) {
            if (!char.IsLetter(c)) {
                continue;
            }
            var i = contest.FindIndex(kv => kv.Key == c);
            if (i < 0) {
                contest.Add(new(c, 1));
            }
            else {
                contest[i] = new(c, contest[i].Value + 1);
            }
        }

        contest.Sort((e1, e2) => e1.Key - e2.Key);
        Console.Write("\n{0}\n\n", string.Join('\n', contest));

        contest.Sort((e1, e2) => e2.Value - e1.Value);
        Console.Write("\n{0}\n\n", string.Join('\n', contest));
    }
```